How to convert current directly to frequency in the simple 555 frequency meter
So I'm working on an audio project, and I need a built-in frequency meter (for tuning the instrument, basically, so the range is like 50 Hz - 5000 Hz with an required accuracy around 1 Hz). I see a few options out there, but they seem complicated. I also know there is a classic 555-version from Forrest Mim's book, a picture of which I've attached here:

I'd like to explore using this design for what I'm envisioning - I'm using 555s to make the instrument / oscillator circuit, I have experience with them, I like the designs in this book, etc.
First, I'll get the meter to be digital - I think you can just purchase little screens that do the same thing as this analog meter, and I think I need that level of precision to differentiate between the 40-50 notes that occur over the range I'm interested in. I can handle that.
What I can't handle is the current to frequency conversion. To use this thing as-is, I would have to build it with specific RC, to get a particular curve. Then find that curve using i.e. oscilloscope ("Calibration"). Then, when I wanted to use it as a frequency meter, read off the curve (in practice I'd use some kind of software lookup). But I want this to be all behind a screen, so that I directly see the frequency on the meter (in principle, I'll be tuning the instrument repeatedly, so this is about convenience).
So, can I do that? A solution with existing, purchasable ICs would be awesome, but I assume that is not possible. If the answer is "arduino" or "Raspberry PI", I'd like to get a sense of what would be required, perhaps a tutorial that is directed towards that specific task, etc. I have experience with software, so I'm not afraid of diving into that, but I just don't have any direct experience with those devices at this moment.
Thanks!

I don't think there's any way to make that circuit precise enough to drive a meter with more than 2 digits.

The answer is probably arduino. with that  you get a crystal based frequency reference so a 5 digit display should be possible - there seem to be plenty of search results.

I'll just say I don't think precision is really the issue. Sure, I want to be able to get the frequency to be within 1 Hz, but the real problem is converting the current through R6 into the correct frequency. I guess there might be some issues with how precise the values of R3 and C3 are (like +/- 5%, whatever), but if I can't read frequency off the meter, it doesn't actually matter how many digits the meter reads (and I only need 3-4 digits in any case).

You can just buy a kit  or LCD frequency meter/generator module  for< than an analog meter would cost, and with a crystal time base and digital display. The former generally use a PIC (you can find free firmware on the net if you want to roll your own) and the latter a Holtek or similar MCU. Or use an Arduino and add an LCD module to display the results digitally in the form you want (plenty of info available with a web search- I've not tried that one, and Instructables is a bit unreliable so caveat emptor).

If you go the Arduino way, it would be better to avoid the Nano which usually uses a resonator so the time base accuracy could be off by 0.5%, which is +/-25Hz at 5kHz.

Do you actually need 1Hz accuracy, or do you need+-2.5% accuracy? 1Hz is roughly +-2.5% at 16Hz (C0), but +-0.005% at 7900Hz (B8), before you even get into the higher harmonics. Remember that the notes are an exponential scale. +-2.5% is more than enough even at B8, but thats a much wider absolute frequency range.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany Thanks for the hit on the kit - that looks slightly more reliable than the one I found. For sure, this is an alternative approach, I wanted to explore using a 555 first, because I have a chance to actually understand the circuit. But yeah, it's a good suggestion.

@user1937198: Yes to all this. I am asking ~1 Hz accuracy based on the range I'm mostly going to be using the thing, 220-800 Hz, and my experience with tuning instruments. I'm mostly just trying to point out that an analog meter that runs 220-880 is not really going to cut it - you'll be able to tell it's out of tune.

@cduston Trying to reach +-1Hz is a huge engineering challenge at the higher end, as error tends to be proportional. And a 0.005% error is really strict. But you don't need that. It might be more helpful to specify your required error in fractional semitones. (1 semitone approximately being equal to 0.25 db of error in equal temperament).

saying you need 1Hz error is saying you need to be able to identify 0.0035 of a semitone at 5000Hz. Which I really doubt you need. Whereas a sphero pointed out a 0.5% time base is accurate enough to give you 0.85 of a semitones accuracy across the full range, and is a lot easier to hit.

You'll never get ±1Hz precision out of this design, except perhaps at very low frequencies. You might expect ±1%, which means a very different thing; ±1% of 20kHz is ±200Hz, but ±1% of 20Hz is ±0.2Hz. Without really analysing that circuit, I couldn't say for sure what the expected precision (in percent, and when properly calibrated) would be, though.
Regardless of that, this design relies on inertia of the analogue moving-coil and needle in the ammeter to "average out" the voltage of pin 3, the 555's output. The role of R5 and R6 is to convert that voltage to a proportional current, so you are not wrong to say that current out is the quantity being measured, though average voltage and current are (almost - ammeter coil inductance notwithstanding) directly proportional to each other here. Measure average voltage, or measure average current, both are equivalent in this application.
If you intend to replace the analogue ammeter with a digital equivalent, then you no longer have intertial mass to do the averaging for you, so you'll need first to find out if your intended meter does any averaging, and over what period. If not, you can expect the meter reading to jump around seemingly randomly.
You can use a capacitor to emulate physical inertia:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The capacitor, in combination with the three resistances, forms a low-pass filter, effectively averaging \$V_3\$, the potential at pin 3. At A you expect potential \$V_A\$ to be:
$$ V_A = V_3\frac{10k + 100}{4.7k + 10k + 100} = 0.68 \times V_3 $$
\$V_B\$ is a variable fraction of that, going from \$V_{B(MAX)} = 100\%\times V_A\$ down to:
$$ V_{B(MIN)} = V_A\frac{100}{10k + 100} \approx 1\%\times V_A $$
Using the values shown, node B will settle at some average potential after a second or so. As a test, use a regular digital multimeter in volts mode, which will have very high input impedance (10MΩ or so) to measure the potential at B for some fixed frequency of input, and verify that it does indeed vary in proportion to input frequency.
Once you've established that it does, then you're ready to employ pretty much any off-the-shelf digital voltmeter.
You could of course use the ADC of a microcontroller (such as the one in an Arduino) to measure \$V_B\$, convert to Hertz, and show the result on a connected display. However, this would make the 555 and its periphery redundant. If you decide to use a microcontroller, then its internal timer hardware (together with your own software) would probably be able to produce a much more accurate measurement of frequency given a digital input. Then all you'd need to do is convert the analogue input signal to an oscillating digital signal, using a comparator:

simulate this circuit
Blue is \$V_{IN}\$, orange is \$V_{OUT}\$:

This also gives you the opportunity to add hysteresis, which I do with positive feedback via R6. Hysteresis here is about 100mV, meaning that the signal will have to be at least 100mV peak-to-peak for the output to transition up and down, but it makes the system much more immune to any noise present in the measured input signal.

Awesome - I appreciate the comment about the averaging, also mentioned by the other answer, since it highlights that replacing the analog meter with a digital one is not as trivial as I thought. The rest is slightly over my head, but I think I understand that once you include the possibility of a micro controller, the 555 becomes pointless, so I might as well give up on this particular plan.

First realize that while many of Forest Mims's circuits are good learning experiences, many are not practical circuits. Especially now, 50 years later.
Build it anyway. I may build it myself out of curiosity, just to see how accurate it can potentially be.
Some improvements and notes:
Analog meters are inherently current meters. To create a voltmeter, you put an appropriate resistor in series. But you are actually measuring an average voltage, so there is no need for a current meter. Digital meters are inherently voltmeters.
The circuit is using the 555 in monostable mode. For each cycle at the input, a fixed length pulse is output. An analog meter has a slow response, so it will automatically average the pulses.
A digital voltmeter may smooth out the pulses and give you a good average. But it may not, add a filter to be safe.
With great care, you should be able to get better linearity than he documented in his graph. You need clean pulses. Overshoot and undershoot are your enemy, they will degrade the accuracy.
The input must have fast transitions. It can't be a sine wave. C1 will convert the input to a narrow pulse that triggers the 555.
The maximum frequency that you can measure will be determined by the 555 output pulse width. At some point, the pulse will not finish before the next trigger at the input.
The output will be highly dependent on the supply voltage. He indicates a supply voltage of 5-15. Any will work (assuming calibration), but it must be fixed and constant.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
A digital voltmeter will usually have an input impedance of 10 Meg. With these modifications, you can't use an analog meter, its impedance will be much lower.
Edit: Built the circuit.
Vcc = 5 V.
I used an ICM7555, an improved version of the 555, mostly because I couldn't find my 555s (antique bin somewhere)
R3 = 2.2k.
C3 = 0.1 uF mylar (ceramics are terrible for this purpose).
R4 isn't needed with the ICM7555, may not help much with a 555 either.
My Fluke 111 DMM averages well, the cap isn't needed (but measurements taken with it).
The linearity is better than Forest measured (probably because my Fluke is much better than whatever analog meter he had laying around).
With these components, it only works up to 4.3 kHz. You will need to tweak components to get to 5k. And realize that when you go past the limit, it will act squirrely.
If you want it calibrated, you will need to add a pot voltage divider.


You built it! Awesome. I appreciate the notes, and the details around how the thing is functioning. The improvements make it quite linear, but doesn't solve the issue of needing software to convert the voltage back to frequency when you read the thing.

I kinda hate giving the answer to the other poster, but the inclusion of the micro controller discussion addresses more directly the issue I am worried about. But still, great answer, and thanks for your improved build. Like you, I might go for it anyway!
